# Extracting temperature from Global Land Data Assimilation System (GLDAS) netcdf4 file using python?

Tags: python, netcdf

I extract temperature data from the netcdf4 file using python I used these code but it returns only null values.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

nc = Dataset("GLDAS_NOAH025_3H.A20170102.0000.021.nc4","r")
for temp in nc.variables['AvgSurfT_inst'] :
    print (temp)
```

Output:

```
[[[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  ..., 
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]]
```

Comment: Can you point to a source for your datafile so we could duplicate?

Comment: Per the image on https://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/GLDAS_NOAH025_3H_V2.1/summary?keywords=GLDAS it looks like the head and tail of the dataset could very well be nulls.

Comment: yes Dave X , tail and head datasets are null. And nc.variables['AvgSurfat_inst'][0,:] show actual result. I solved my problem. And thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the image on https://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/GLDAS_NOAH025_3H_V2.1/summary?keywords=GLDAS it looks like the head and tail of the dataset could very well be nulls.